# Schrollable dialogbox without (the desktop) window

Tags: c++, winapi, scroll, dialog, c++17

This example of scrollable dialog box
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/32925/scrollable-dialog-in-pure-win32-api

works fine, and display the dialog box
My question does this dialog box = the desktop window
or the desktop window missing?
any attempt to place the code in vs2022 C++ desktop
application with purpose to show the desktop window
and the dialog box on top... failed
this the WinMain and DialogBox macro

```
int WINAPI _tWinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    //HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPWSTR /*lpCmdLine*/,
    int /*nShowCmd*/)  //   THIS DIFFERENT NCMDSHOW USED IN MAINWIN
{
    DialogBox(
        hInstance,
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),
        GetDesktopWindow(),
        SD_DialogProc);

    return 0;
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK SD_DialogProc(
    HWND hwndDlg,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    HANDLE_MSG(hwndDlg, WM_INITDIALOG, SD_OnInitDialog);
    HANDLE_MSG(hwndDlg, WM_COMMAND, SD_OnCommand);
    HANDLE_MSG(hwndDlg, WM_SIZE, SD_OnSize);
    HANDLE_MSG(hwndDlg, WM_HSCROLL, SD_OnHScroll);
    HANDLE_MSG(hwndDlg, WM_VSCROLL, SD_OnVScroll);
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Dialog

```
IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 316, 185
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CENTER | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT1,7,6,291,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    PUSHBUTTON      "Button1",IDC_BUTTON1,6,30,50,14
    CONTROL         "Check1",IDC_CHECK1,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,6,54,39,10
    GROUPBOX        "Static",IDC_STATIC,7,70,110,50
    CONTROL         "Radio1",IDC_RADIO1,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP,12,84,38,10
    CONTROL         "Radio2",IDC_RADIO2,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP,12,102,38,10
    LTEXT           "Sample Static Control",IDC_STATIC,6,126,108,8
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,194,154,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,248,154,50,14
END
```

THE NEEDED INFORMATION .RC  .H  FOR THE SCHROLL DIALOG BOX HAS BEEN INCORPOERATED
TO THE PROJECT APPLICATION WITH CREATEWINDOW().

NOTE:  this code has no WinProc(){ }

Obviously, This WinMain a valid entry point but no CreateWindow with
instance and registration? we should not expect to see
the desktop window?

Thus this WinMain allow only the initialization of DialogBox, but
does not have any reference to the desktop CreateWindow

tried to include/merge the code with vs2022  C++/desktop , the
desk top window appears , but the dialog box failed to appear,
after many attempt how to include the DialogBox Macro,
in WinMain or Instance or registration...etc....

An intersting problem:
this code has solution explorer appearing next to code editor
in application file, the .sln when clicked open a project in
vs2022.
When the .rc or any other module clicked form the file directory
it will not open in the applicated text editor
""  fatal error RC1015: canot open include file 'afxres.h'  ""
MFC is loaded to vs2022....
However;
will open only in another projectX that opened along with
the Schroll project.

Does the dialog box considered now the desktop menu?
can this be with  desktop window to show the application
element and this good example of dialog box?

documentation show the modal dialog box code located under
WM-DELETEITEM  (learn: deleteItme example)

```
case IDM_DELETEITEM: 
            if (DialogBox(hinst, 
                          MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_DELETEITEM), 
                          hwnd, 
                          (DLGPROC)DeleteItemProc)==IDOK) 
            {
                // Complete the command; szItemName contains the 
                // name of the item to delete. 
            }
```

this code initiated form the -tWinMain() {  DialogBox(  ); macro  }

where to locate the DialogBox macro in a project application
As I failed to get the it to be called under WM_INITDIALOG
PLACING  OF SD_DialogProc() UNDER WM_INITDIALOG IN WinProc()

The WinProc()  section that attempted to use?
How  do we get the WinMain to call WM_INITDIALOG ???

```
 case WM_INITDIALOG: 
     //  add
     // Get the owner window and dialog box rectangles. 
     //You create a modal dialog box by using the DialogBox function.
     //  You must specify the identifier or name of a dialog box template resource
     //  and a pointer to the dialog box procedure.
     //  The DialogBox function loads the template, 
     // displays the dialog box, and processes all user input 
     // the application specifies its main window as the owner window for the dialog box. 
   
     if ((hwndOwner = GetParent(hwndDlg)) == NULL)
     {
         hwndOwner = GetDesktopWindow();
     }

     GetWindowRect(hwndOwner, &rcOwner);
     GetWindowRect(hwndDlg, &rcDlg);
     CopyRect(&rc, &rcOwner);

     DialogBox(
         hInstance,
         MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),
         GetDesktopWindow(),  // RETURN HANDLE TO MAIN WINDOW JUST LIKE hwnd, 
         SD_DialogProc);
    // SD_DialogProc;

     // Offset the owner and dialog box rectangles so that right and bottom 
 // values represent the width and height, and then offset the owner again 
 // to discard space taken up by the dialog box. 

     OffsetRect(&rcDlg, -rcDlg.left, -rcDlg.top);
     OffsetRect(&rc, -rc.left, -rc.top);
     OffsetRect(&rc, -rcDlg.right, -rcDlg.bottom);

     // The new position is the sum of half the remaining space and the owner's 
// original position. 

     SetWindowPos(hwndDlg,
         HWND_TOP,
         rcOwner.left + (rc.right / 2),
         rcOwner.top + (rc.bottom / 2),
         0, 0,          // Ignores size arguments. 
         SWP_NOSIZE);

     if (GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)wParam) != ID_ITEMNAME)
     {
         SetFocus(GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, ID_ITEMNAME));
         return FALSE;
     }

     return TRUE;

     break;
```

That all, sorry for being to much to write!

All the above done and nothing worked to get desktop window
and this code for the DialogBox() nacro

Comment: The `DESIGNINFO` section is also important. Does my answer solve your problem? Or you may show your whole Resource-Definition File (.rc).

Answer (score 0):

There could be some issues in your merged [Resource-Definition File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/sample-resource-definition-file) (.rc).
The following code works for me.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

//IDD_ABOUTBOX DIALOGEX 0, 0, 102, 43
//your definition

IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 316, 185
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CENTER | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT1,7,6,291,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    PUSHBUTTON      "Button1",IDC_BUTTON1,6,30,50,14
    CONTROL         "Check1",IDC_CHECK1,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,6,54,39,10
    GROUPBOX        "Static",IDC_STATIC1,7,70,110,50
    CONTROL         "Radio1",IDC_RADIO1,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP,12,84,38,10
    CONTROL         "Radio2",IDC_RADIO2,"Button",BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP,12,102,38,10
    LTEXT           "Sample Static Control",IDC_STATIC,6,126,108,8
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,194,154,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,248,154,50,14
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_ABOUTBOX, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        TOPMARGIN, 7
    END

    IDD_DIALOG1, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 298
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 168
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

`DialogBox(hInst,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),hWnd,SD_DialogProc);`

Resource.h

```
#define IDC_STATIC                      -1

#define IDD_DIALOG1                     111
#define IDC_BUTTON1                     1101
#define IDC_CHECK1                      1102
#define IDC_EDIT1                       1103
#define IDC_RADIO1                      1104
#define IDC_RADIO2                      1105
#define IDC_STATIC1                     1106
```